# how to use cached renderer in pug in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching, pug

I benchmarked and I noticed (from the docs) that everytime pug engine renders templates (pug.render) unless cache option is set to TRUE.
I can set from pug but how can I set while using express?

Comment: pug must cache in prod mode, try set production

Comment: thats for advice. I one more time read the caching. I can change cache option on pug but now I should find how to do in expressjs. 

https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#options-cache